# Can't set Content-length header for POST method

Tags: windows-phone-7, http-headers, http-post

We had this problem for a while, just this morning I was able to set Content-length header for POST method, but now it doesn't work anymore. Why is it? I haven't done anything, I heard that this is restricted but I could use it just fine yesterday:

```
request.Headers["Content-Length"] = byteArray.Length.ToString();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Silverlight 3 / WP 7.0 you can't set the Content-Length header, this is done for you by the http stack.

Silverlight 4 / (WP 7.1 ?) has a `ContentLength` property but you would only set is when using the ClientHTTP stack with the `AllowWriteStreamBuffering` set to false.